# Sympy - get access to the single parts of the solution of solve()

Tags: python, sympy

I trying to solve a set of equations:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers import *
a,b,c = symbols('a,b,c')

equations=[
    Eq(a*1**2+b*2+c,3),
    Eq(a*4**2+b*5+c,6),
    Eq(a*7**2+b*8+c,9),

]
solve(equations)
```

That works quite well... I'll get an output like

```
[{a: 1, c:-2, b:3}]
```

But now I want to select the solution for the symbol c and make it processible. How can I do that. I have not found anything in the documentation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371093/sympy-how-to-save-solution-from-solve-for-reuse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result seems to be a list of dicts so you should be able to use the standard Python operations

```
c_solutions = [sol[c] for sol in solutions]
```

Comment: YES! You're great! That works:
    c_solutions = [sol[c] for sol in solve(equations,dict=True)]